# Regarding a result of I.Vekua on integral equations of first kind

Tags: reference-request, integral-operators

Suppose $k\in L^2([0,1]\times[0,1])$ is a symmetric kernel. Presumably the following is true(under the assumption that $k$ is weakly singular):

Either 
$$\displaystyle\int_0^1f(y)k(x,y)dy=0$$or

$$\displaystyle\int_0^1f(y)k(x,y)dy=1$$
has a non-trivial solution. In some papers (for instance in [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.205.6303&rep=rep1&type=pdf))this result is attributed to Muskhelishvili and I.Vekua. Unfortunately the right edition of the book(s) is hard to find and the edition I have access to, does not contain such a result.